# How to show repeatable metabox value in ionic app

Tags: rest, api, ionic2

Developing an ionic app with WordPress back-end, can any one help me out how to show repeatable metabox value in my ionic app, below is JSON response (REST API).

```
_meta_child_details 
0   
child_name  "Mayank"
_meta_child_hobby   "Cricket"
child_dob   "10/23/2017"
1   
child_name  "Dev"
_meta_child_hobby   "Hockey"
child_dob   "11/20/2017"
```

I want to show both name, hobby and DOB

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to write full code for you ? i can help a little bit for you .but try once before post

put following code in your ts file .

```
this.myvariable=[
{"child_name":"Mayank",
"_meta_child_hobby" :  "Cricket",
"child_dob":"10/23/2017"},
 {"child_name" :"Dev",
"_meta_child_hobby":"Hockey",
"child_dob" :"11/20/2017"}
]
```

This is the right json which was coming from api .
Now use this in your html .

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let feed of myvariable">
Name : {{feed.child_name}} <br>
Hobby : {{feed._meta_child_hobby}} <br>
DOB : {{feed.child_dob}}
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Thank you for effort and reply, same process I had followed but did not get result.

Comment: share your error what your are getting in console. make any live running code then i can help you